# xts subset quarterly data

Tags: r, xts

I want to subset a range of quarterly data held inside an xts object.

I see the documentation says "xts provides facilities for indexing based on any of the current time-based classes. These include yearqtr"

However I have tried the following, which do produce a range of data but not the dates I request.

```
a = as.xts(ts(rnorm(20), start=c(1980,1), freq=4))
a["1983"] # Returns 1983Q2 - 1984Q1 ?
a["1983-01/"] # Begins in 1983Q2 ?
a["1981-01/1983-03"] # Returns 1981Q2 - 1983Q2 ?

a[as.yearqtr("1981 Q2")] # Correct
a[as.yearqtr("1981 Q1")/as.yearqtr("1983 Q3")] # Does not work
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a timezone issue.  The xts index is *always* a POSIXct object, even if the index class is something else.  Like a `Date` classed index, the `yearqtr` (and `yearmon`) classed index should have the timezone set to `"UTC"`.

```
> a <- as.xts(ts(rnorm(20), start=c(1980,1), freq=4), tzone="UTC")
> a["1983"]
              [,1]
1983 Q1  1.4877302
1983 Q2 -0.4594768
1983 Q3 -0.1906189
1983 Q4 -1.1518943
Warning message:
timezone of object (UTC) is different than current timezone ().
```

You can safely ignore the warning.  If it really bothers you, you can set your R session's timezone to `"UTC"` via:

```
> Sys.setenv(TZ="UTC")
> a <- as.xts(ts(rnorm(20), start=c(1980,1), freq=4))
> a["1983"]
               [,1]
1983 Q2  1.84636890
1983 Q3 -0.06872544
1983 Q4 -2.29822631
1984 Q1 -1.46025131
```

This will never work:

```
a[as.yearqtr("1981 Q1")/as.yearqtr("1983 Q3")] # Does not work
```

It looks like you're trying to do something like: `a["1981 Q1/1983 Q3"]`, which isn't supported because "YYYY Qq" is not an ISO8601 format.

Comment: Is there any way then to correctly request a range of data between  quarters? I have tried a few things such as: `a["1981.25/1984.00"]` and `window(a, start=c(1981,2), end=c(1983,1))`  and  `window(ts(a), start=c(1981,2), end=c(1983,1))
` but I can not get these to work.

Comment: @moof: just use a month in the quarter. `a["1981-01/1983-09"]` will return 1981Q1-1983Q3.

Comment: Ok I see now, after the time zone change it works. It looks like the first quarter you want must use the first month of that quarter, and the end quarter can use any month from that quarter. Many thanks.